# Android - How to retrieve list of registered geofences

Tags: android, android-intent, geofencing

How can I determine all geofences registered for an application?

After registering GeoFences with `LocationClient.addGeofences()`，I waited for `onAddGeofencesResuls()`（which returned SUCCESS) and tried to use `LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent)` with the same intent I used for registration, but I only got `null`.

Answer (score 10):

I assume you are trying to compare the registered geofences with the ones that you have persisted in your own database.

I tried to do that as well with my app, but it seems like the API hints that this is not the way to go. So what I do now is just to simply register geofences, it will automatically replace those that I have registered before. And when some that I have registered fires, and I am supposed to remove them, I will remove them in the firing Intent.

Another possibility is to register all the geofences to have 24 hours time limit, and have the code register the geofences at least once everyday.

Comment: Has anyone figured out the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

getTriggeringGeofences() only returns Geofences that triggered a transition last time. That's why it returns null if no transition occurrs. Refer to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getTriggeringGeofences%28android.content.Intent%29

Answer (score -1):

```
GeofencingRequest.getGeofences();
```

This method return a list of geofences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).